# Не срабатывает триггер @Pointcut / Spring

Tags: java, spring-aop

Добрый день, вопрос в следующем: 
Есть простейшее приложение с java конфиг файлом, есть аспект, который при срабатывании метода должен просто в консоль вывести сообщение, но сам срез "@Pointcut" во время работы метода не срабатывает.

Класс аспекта:

```
package ***.aspects;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component("statisticsAspect")
public class StatisticsAspect {

public StatisticsAspect() {
}

@Before("fileEventLoggerMethod()")
public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println("BEFORE : " +
            joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName()
            + " " +
            joinPoint.getSignature().getName()
    );
}

@Pointcut("execution(* *.logEvent(..))")
public void fileEventLoggerMethod() {
    System.out.println("Выполнение файлового логгера");
}

@Pointcut("execution(* *.logEvent(..))")
public void allEventLoggerMethod() {
    System.out.println("Выполнение любого логгера");
}
```

}

Класс конфигурации:

```
package core.config;

import core.beans.App;
import core.loggers.EventLogger;
importcore.loggers.impl.FileEventLogger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("spring.core")
@PropertySource("classpath:file.event.logger.properties")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AppConfig {

@Autowired
@Qualifier(value ="combinedLogger")
private EventLogger combinedLogger;

@Autowired
@Qualifier(value = "fileEventLogger")
private EventLogger fileEventLogger;

@Autowired
@Qualifier(value ="consoleEventLogger")
private EventLogger consoleEventLogger;

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}

@Bean
public static AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor autowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {
    return new AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
}

@Bean(name = "app")
public App getApp() {
   System.out.println(fileEventLogger + " this logger");
      return new App(fileEventLogger);
}
```

}

Класс простого логгера, где срабатывает сам метод:

```
@Component("fileEventLogger")


 public class FileEventLogger implements EventLogger {
    protected String fileName;
    protected File file;

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }


    public FileEventLogger() {
    }

    @Autowired
    public FileEventLogger(@Value("${fileName}")String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws IOException{
        this.file = new File(fileName);
    }

    @Override
    public void logEvent(Event event) {
         try {
            System.out.println(event + " This event");
            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, event.toString(), true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Невозможно записать данные в файл " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FileEventLogger{" +
                "fileName='" + fileName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Ксласс с методом main:

```
package core.beans;

import core.config.AppConfig;
import core.loggers.EventLogger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class App {
@Autowired
@Qualifier("client")
private Client client;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("Event")
private Event event;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("holliday")
private Holliday holliday;


@Autowired
@Qualifier(value = "consoleEventLogger")
private EventLogger consoleEventLogger;


@Autowired
@Qualifier(value = "fileEventLogger")
private EventLogger defaultLogger;

private EventLogger logger;

public App() {
}

@Autowired
public App(@Value("#{ T(core.beans.Event).isDay() ? fileEventLogger : consoleEventLogger }") EventLogger logger) {
    this.logger = logger;
}

public String logEvent(String msg, EventType type) {
    System.out.println(logger);
    if (logger == null) {
        logger = defaultLogger;
    }
    holliday.congradulate();
    System.out.println(client);
    String message = msg.replaceAll(
            String.valueOf(client.getId()), client.getFullName());
    System.out.println(message);
    logger.logEvent(event);
    return("This return value from logEvent() !!" );
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
    App app = (App) ctx.getBean("app");
    app.logEvent("Some event for user 1", EventType.INFO);
    app.logEvent("Some event for user 2", EventType.ERROR);
}
```

}

При вызове самого метода в fileEventLogger я конкретно получаю вывод сообщения на консоль, но pointcut в это время молчит как партизан, я пробовал вводить другое имя класса, т.е. при неправильном вводе - бросается сразу исключение. Конфигурация вся полностью на аннотациях, а в примерах, котрые находились в инете в основном использовался xml, поэтому и создал новый топик.

Comment: У вас задан компонент '@Component("statisticsAspect")', но в конфигурации квалифаера с именем 'statisticsAspect' я не вижу. Проверьте, все ли у вас корректно, или вы выложили не актуальный код.

Comment: да квалифаер в аспекте не обязателен, т.е. в апп. конфигурации мне не нужно его получать явно, имя компонента я указывал для будущего удобства, т.е. его можно убрать и ничего не изменится

Comment: И все таки я бы посоветовал вам сначала запустить эту конфигурацию на 1-м именованном бине. Таким образом стало бы очевидно, где кроется проблема - в именовании/инжектировании бинов или же в чем то ещё..

Comment: ну скажем так - я убрал имя компонента в аспекте, запускаю - advice @Before срабатывает как и до этого, если я создаю  ещё один advice, например:     @AfterReturning(pointcut = "fileEventLoggerMethod()",
            returning = "retVal")
    public void logAfter(Object retVal) {
        System.out.println("Returned value : " + retVal);
    }     то срабатывает он тоже безо всяких, выводит сообщение, что метод ничего ине вернул, или Вы имели ввиду, чтобы я проинжектил бин именно аспекта в какой-то класс?

Comment: я вам предлагаю временно убрать все лишнее. 1 - имя и компонент у аспекта. 2 - в конфигурации инжектить конкретно ваш логгер (пока убрать другие возможные имплементации). (на самом деле, тут можно просто убедиться дебагом, что инжектиться  именно то, что вам нужно). В целом, я предлагаю посмотреть дебагом внимательно на то, что у вас будет загружено рантайм, сделать это будет намного проще если пока убрать лишние реализации логгера.

Comment: И да, попробуйте убрать ограничения из аспекта - пусть он пока логирует абсолютно все..

Comment: Я сделал так: в конфигурации инжектится только бин с файловым логгером и передаётся в конструктор главного класса, который собсвтенно его и использует, имя компнотента в аспекте я убрал, дебаггом можно отследить, что выполняется сам метод этого логгера, а так же advicы @Before и AfterReturning

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38522/discussion-between-go2bed-and-evgeny-lazarev).

Comment: ответил в чат..